# Maps are objects but what is the type of value inside the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I was recently learning maps and when I tried the code below:

```
let a = [
    [false, 1],
    ['1', 'str1'],
    [1, 'num1'],
    [true, 'bool1']
]

let map1 = new Map(a);

console.log(map1);
```

It output me:

```
Map { false => 1, '1' => 'str1', 1 => 'num1', true => 'bool1' }
```

So I can see it's an object(due to {}) but what is the type of value inside the curly braces. I cannot understand. So please anyone tell what is the type of the value and can I get the value from the key without using get method.
By the way I am using node js to execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

The output you're seeing is a *formatting convention* for how to display Maps when examined in the console. The map doesn't actually hold the keys and values as own-properties - rather, the keys and values are held *internally*, available only to the internals of the Map implementation, which exposes them through the various Map methods like `.values()`, `.keys()`, `.get()`, and so on.

> can I get the value from the key without using get method.

I suppose you could use `.entries()` to turn the Map into an array, then look through the array for the matching key:

```js
let a = [
    [false, 1],
    ['1', 'str1'],
    [1, 'num1'],
    [true, 'bool1']
]

let map1 = new Map(a);

const entries = [...map1.entries()];

const entry = entries.find(e => e[0] === 1);
console.log(entry[1]);
```

But that's really weird.

There's no way to get the saved values on a Map *without* using one of the Map's built-in methods - but that's OK, since you *should* always be using the built-in methods to process a Map. Go ahead and use `.get`.

Comment: Ok now I understood thanks a lot for answering the question I was confused a lot but now understood the point.